# Blocked async call in WPF C# 5.0 and .NET 4.5

Tags: .net, async-await, c#-5.0

Here is a snippet of code that I am having problems with the UI blocking during a long running task.  I have seen other examples that seems to do the same thing, but this doesn't work.  I think it is something simple.

What am I missing?

```
public class ClipManager
{
    async public Task<int> AddNewClipsAsync()
    {
        int rc = AddNewClips();  // does the work
        return rc;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
private async void UpdateClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check event to update library from WindowsMain.xml.cs
    private async void UpdateClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        UpdateBtn.IsEnabled = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Start of Update");
        var cm = ClipManagement.Create();

        int rc = await cm.AddNewClipsAsync();  // long running method

        // UI unfreezes at this point
        Console.WriteLine("After Update of Update");
        await Task.Delay(30000);  // just debugging code
        Console.WriteLine("After delay");
        LibraryDG.Items.Refresh();
        UpdateBtn.IsEnabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [`async` does not run your code on a background thread.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/async-await-faq.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current `AddNewClips` will block the UI.  You need to wrap it in a `Task.Run`, so that it runs in the background:

```
public class ClipManager
{
    async public Task<int> AddNewClipsAsync()
    {
        int rc = await Task.Run<int>(() => AddNewClips());  // does the work
        return rc;
    }
}
```

The code above assumes that `AddNewClips` doesn't make any UI calls - that it just processes some data, and then returns some kind of result.

Comment: Great answer!  This is exactly what I was missing.  It now works as I expected.